# TypeScript with React's useContext? property does not exist

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Trying to use TypeScript with React's useContext. Thought I had it figured out but get an error stating that the props do not exist when I destructure the custom hook.

Here's my custom hook - no TypeScript errors from what I see

```
type AppContext = {
  handleLogin: HandleLogin;
};

type HandleLogin = (email: string, password: string) => void;

const AuthContext = createContext<AppContext | null>(null);

export const AuthProvider = ({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  const router = useRouter();

  // Handle login
  const handleLogin: HandleLogin = async (email: string, password: string) => {
    const userData = await login(email, password);
    setUser(userData);
  };

  return (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={{ handleLogin }}>
      {children}
    </AuthContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

But when I destructure the hook like so...

```
  const { handleLogin } = useAuth();
```

I get the following error - * Property 'handleLogin' does not exist on type 'AppContext | null'.*

I get the same error if I include another value or function within the context's value but run into the same error. Really not sure what I'm missing.

Comment: You've said the context can be `null` (or `AppContext`): `const AuthContext = createContext<AppContext | null>(null);`. You can't destructure `null`. Before you can do any destructuring, you need to ensure that you don't have `null`.

Comment: What is `useAuth`? What does it return?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're assigning the initial value of context as `null`, so you need to make sure the context is not null when you're restructuring. Or you can tell typescript that context will always be `AppContext`.

```
const AuthContext = createContext<AppContext>({} as AppContext);
```

It's type-safe because the value will be set on the Provider when your component uses the context.

UPDATE: The below is probably a better solution.

```
const AuthContext = createContext<AppContext|undefined>(undefined);

export default function useAuthContext() {
  const context = useContext(AuthContext);
  if (!context) throw Error("useAuthContext can only be used inside an AuthProvider");
  return context;
}
```

This gives you the type safety without any conversions. Plus a runtime check that the hook is used properly. Note that it depends on the initial value of the context being undefined.

Comment: You don't need to pass the generic with a cast

Comment: just being explicit.

Comment: Saying something (`{}`) is an `AppContext` when it isn't one is not a good idea.